# Save Gatling results as a JSON or xml file

Tags: json, scala, performance-testing, scala-collections, gatling

Recently I have started using Gatling but to integrate Gatling with Jenkins I need the out put in the JSON or xml format. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from [Stéphane](https://github.com/slandelle)  that Gatling currently not supports to such features .

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean integrate Gatling with Jenkins, does the [Jenkins Gatling Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gatling+Plugin) ([Scala RC2 Doc](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/extensions/jenkins_plugin.html)) do what you want?